# ISERROR function in excel to avoid #Value with the expected date result

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I need the below formula with `ISERRoR` function to avoid:

> Value errors with the expected result in date format than the number format.

```
=IF(DAY(P20)>10,ABS(MONTH(P20)+1&"/1/"&YEAR(P20)),ABS(MONTH(20)&"/1/"&YEAR(P20)))
```

In P20 I will insert a date eg: `09/24/2013` and the result I get in P21 currently is `41548` but the expected result is `10/01/2013`.

Answer (score 2):

Format the result cell with a date format of your choice.